# Facebook SDK location field is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My website that parses Facebook feed suddenly stopped to work with following error message: 
" location field is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 12"

I am making only two calls to the Facebook graph:

```
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$appId}&client_secret={$appSecret}");
    //print_r($authToken); //1

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{$page_id}/feed?{$authToken}&limit={$limit}");
        displayData($json_object); //2
```

1. gets the authentication token
2. Tries to access the page feed.

I don't add any location paramaters, therefore I don't understand why it doesn't work?
Any help will be appreciated.
Janusz

Answer (score 0):

Wow! It was the limit (&limit={$limit}) paramater in the query:

```
$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{$page_id}/feed?{$authToken}&limit={$limit}");
```

Once I removed everything started to work like it should.

Comment: Doesn’t make much sense though, that you would get that error message then … Can you verify what your `$limit` variable actually contained?