# PHP: Facebook SDK locations API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm looking to get the user_location on login but it doesn't seem to work. I presumed the parameter in the graph was "locations" but it claims it's been deprecated as of 2.2. Are you not able to get user location anymore or is it because it's an array I need to do something extra? I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
$profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email,gender');
$requestLikes = $fb->get('/me/likes?limit=20');
$requestlocation = $fb->get('/me/locations');

$profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
$likes = $requestLikes->getGraphEdge();
$location = $requestlocation->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```

My error:

> Graph returned an error: (#12) locations API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

Comment: does this help [facebook-sdk-location-field-is-deprecated-for-versions-v2-3-and-higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481001/facebook-sdk-location-field-is-deprecated-for-versions-v2-3-and-higher)?

Comment: Thanks but I saw it earlier. I believe he had a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I solved it. I don't know why but when I took "location" in with the array profile[] I was able to retrieve it. Not exactly sure why this works yet.

Comment: Because you are now asking for the `location` _field_ of the user object, which is something completely different than the [`locations` _edge_](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/user/locations) you tried to ask for previously ...